# My code is not working without an alert(); function in the start

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire a :click(); function but unable to do that I don't know why but when I type the :alert(); function in start then my code works I am stuck in this situation.

I search over internet but no success.Any help from you is very appreciable.

HTML:

```
<div class="edit-options-dated">
    <span><?php echo date('H:i:m', (time()-strtotime($note->getCreationDatetime()))); ?></span>         
    <ul class="pull-right edit-task-icons">
        <li class="delete-task"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></li>
        <li class="edit-task"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></li>
        <li class="setting-task"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="settings-task-options">
        <h3>note groups</h3>    
        <li><a href="#">new</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Affiliate Tasks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">next week</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {

// alert('ok');

$('li.setting-task').on('click', function() {

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.settings-task-options').toggle();

});

$('li.delete-task').click(function() {

    $('.delete-2').slideDown();

});

});
```

Comment: Can you debug this a little?  When you attach the event handlers, are any matching elements found at all?  Is the click handler executing but simply not finding elements to modify?  Where/how specifically is this failing?

Comment: Does it work if you use `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`?

Comment: Remove `window).load(`

Comment: @Barmar yes I already tried the solution you mentioned but no success

Comment: @David I recheck all the points you mentioned but negative

Comment: @migg apply your option but no success

Comment: @qarar: Your code works just fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/zg7kmhpb/  Can you demonstrate some way to replicate the problem?

Comment: @David I check all the method but JTC method works for me do you know why?

Comment: Are you loading any of the elements into the DOM dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
$(function(){ // shorthand for document ready - document is safely loaded
    $(document.body).on('click', 'li.setting-task' ,function(e){
      $(this).parent().parent().find('.settings-task-options').toggle();
    });
  });
```

JQuery on - info [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
document.body basically search the body part of your document for select element and makes event for it
```

Comment: this works very happy with solution but can you describe this because I never use this method

Comment: Thanks for your help very appreciated

Answer (score 2):

instead of `$(window).load();` you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  //code here
});
```

may be you need to [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// alert('ok');

 $('body').on('click','li.setting-task', function() {

      $(this).parent().parent().find('.settings-task-options').toggle();

  });

  $('body').on('click','li.delete-task',function() {

    $('.delete-2').slideDown();

  });

});
```

Comment: `$(window).on('load', ...)` is the same as `$(window).load(...)`.

Comment: @Barmar This is not .. I just remember I used it before and its not the same ..I really don't remember well where and how but that's it  may be in another case than this..  but to not make OP confused about it ..  I deleted it ..

Comment: No success @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: Thanks for solution @Mohamed-Yousef